# Sum range in Google Sheets of only unique values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula to sum a column of values. But I only want to sum the rows that have an ID that are unique among the entire range. See the example below where I have 6 rows, but there are only 3 unique IDs. My ideal outcome is a sum of 6 by adding one instance of UNIQUEID-00A, UNIQUEID-00B, and UNIQUEID-00C.

**Notes:**

- A unique ID will always have the same value. For example, if UNIQUEID-00A were listed 1 or 100 times, the associated value will always be 1. So I don't need the formula to account for a scenario where the duplicate IDs have different values.
- There may be instances where Column A (the ID) and Column B (the value) will not be sitting side-by-side. It might be that 2, 3, or more columns are in between the two columns.
- The IDs and values could be 6 rows tall, or hundreds of rows tall. For that reason I'd like to use something like `A2:A` to target the IDs rather than having to specify a specific start and end point like `A2:A7`.

See the linked Google Sheet below for a copy of this.

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| UNIQUEID-00A | 1 |
| UNIQUEID-00B | 2 |
| UNIQUEID-00C | 3 |
| UNIQUEID-00A | 1 |
| UNIQUEID-00B | 2 |
| UNIQUEID-00C | 3 |

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bU4J1RL5S0a_NvFjW_KVpiKi8603Tj9iVPeNzBlw-OA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the above table in A1:B7:

```
=sum(index(unique(A2:B7),,2))
```

UNIQUE returns the distinct rows of the range, INDEX (with column parameter = 2) to return only the value column, then SUM the result.

EDIT Based on the updated requirements, with the IDs in, for example, column A and the values to be summed in column C, use something like:

```
=sum(index(unique({A2:A,C2:C}),,2))
```

I'm assuming that there is no data below your input table. The UNIQUE here will return an extra blank row because of the unlimited range, but SUM will disregard it.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented this in my file and found it didn't work because there are some factors that I did not expect to be an issue. I updated my post to highlight those. I'll put them here too: 

- There may be instances where Column A (the ID) and Column B (the value) will not be sitting side-by-side. It might be that 2, 3, or more columns are in between the two columns. 
- The IDs and values could be 6 rows tall, or hundreds of rows tall. For that reason I'd like to use something like A2:A to target the IDs rather than having to specify a specific start and end point like A2:A7.

Comment: Your updated edit worked great. Can I ask why the ranges need to be enclosed in `{ }`?

Comment: It's because I don't know from your description if the columns in-between the ID and value columns are such that they also have a unique association with each ID - if they don't then UNIQUE would return additional rows and the sum would be wrong. So instead we use array literals (curly brackets) to only refer to the columns specifically required.

Comment: Thanks! Last question, any way to utilize this in a SUMIF formula so that I can check against a value in a third column?

Comment: I think you'll need to submit this as a new and separate question.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUM(SORTN(B3:B, 9^9, 2, A3:A, 1))
```

[image]

- sum `B` column
- while returning all rows `9^9`
- that are unique `2`
- within `A` column
- in whatever order `1`

Comment: Thank you, this works great. And I appreciate the explanation. Why does `9^9` equal all rows?

Comment: @jkupczak coz: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYL7r.png eg. way higher number as possible rows in google sheets. if you got only 1000 rows you can use 1001 or 8456 or 45743574 or 99999 or whatever you wish... it just needs to be higher than total number of rows

Comment: Thanks! Last question, is there any way to combine this with an IF statement? So some all of the values with a unique ID, but also only if a value in Column C = something. I tried turning the SUM formula into a SUMIF or SUMIFs and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @jkupczak try like this maybe: `=SUM(INDEX(SORTN(FILTER(A3:B, C3:C="something"), 9^9, 2, 1, 1),,2))`